# Websphere Data source UTF8 connection parameter

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, websphere, jndi, websphere-8

I have to define the UTF8 character encoding connection parameter in the websphere JDBC datasource settings.

I didn't find any option to configure the connection parameter

**?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8**

Eg:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/DatabaseName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Is there any way to configure the **characterEncoding** connection parameter in the Websphere JDBC data source ?

Comment: you tagged  different RDBMS products . Each may have a different method , or not require any connection setting at all (e.g. Db2-LUW).

Comment: More confusingly you tag [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:db2]] but your code says MySQL. I've removed the tags as they don't appear to match the question. [Edit] your question and tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS.

Comment: I'd ask if it's even related to the SQL _language_...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?!?

Comment: DB :SQL server , Code : Java Open JPA, server : websphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest setting that I see on the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` with values of `true` or `false`, which appears to be a way of getting PreparedStatement.setString and a few other methods to supply parameters to the database as unicode prior to the introduction of methods such as PreparedStatement.setNString in JDBC 4.0, which would always use unicode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, It solved my issue.                            
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-non-ascii-character-support-websphere-application-server-version-85-or-later-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

If the database supports setting the property "characterEncoding", you can simply create a custom datasource property for it, with the value you need.  If the database supports supports url connection (as in your example), you can also just include it as part of your connection URL, which can also be set as a custom datasource property.